# Open source software for building/designing a house?

Tags: architecture, open-source, 3d, modeling

Are there any open source tools for building or designing houses? Does it have many features, like calculating costs or simulating extreme weather conditions/aging, etc?

I had the idea to start up a project like this, or join it; I think it would be really neat, but I couldn't find anything on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.osalt.com/autocad)'s a list of opensource alternatives to autocad.

Answer (score 1):

Red Hat Magazine [ran a story](http://www.redhat.com/magazine/014dec05/features/construction/) a few years back that covered building a house start to finish using an open source philosophy.  It includes a few paragraphs on available software tools.

Answer (score 1):

For external views (with weather lighting etc) google sketchup is good.
For engineering drawings any free cad will do, look at the intellicad based ones on windows